# Table row is highlighted while scrolling the table

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want rows in my table to be highlighted when I press them. However, my implementation of this feature leads to the following: when I scroll the table (just scroll, I'm not intended to press table rows), system interprets it as table-row-press and highlights the row.
How to make system highlight row only when I don't scroll the table?

I've made example project, it consists of 3 files: Class definition, XML layout and XML file where it is specified what to do when table row is pressed.
Here they are:

Class Definition

```
    public class RowHighlightTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TableLayout mainTable=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
        Resources r=getResources();
        // We gonna have 25 rows in our table
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            // Set up each row
            TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
            row.setMinimumHeight(60);
            row.setClickable(true);
            row.setBackgroundDrawable(r.getDrawable(R.drawable.table_row));

            // Add a textView to each row to be able to distinguish them
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("row " + i);
            row.addView(tv);
            mainTable.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
}
```

XML layout: res/layout/main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

3rd one, res/drawable/table_row.xml, it's specified here that table rows should be white by default and dark when pressed:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

How to make system not highlight the row when I scroll the table?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way you're trying to do this is not the right way.

Why didn't you try to use ListView instead of a Table inside a ScrollView ? The difficult scrolling/selection handling is already done and fits your needs...

Comment: I found a way to do handle it myself, but yeah, a listview would have been the better alternative...